# Can't access text of an element in an array using PageObject and Watir

Tags: arrays, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have an array that I collected:

```
array= @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links
```

I am then trying to access the text on a specific element in the array iterating over the array like this:

```
array.each_with_index do |i, index|
```

If I do something like:

```
array[index]
```

I get back the anchor element object. And if I do:

```
array[index].element
```

I will get back an HTML element object. But if I try to get anything element specific such as:

```
array[index].text
array[index].value
```

then I get an "unable to locate element" error.

I am using Watir, Page Object, and Ruby.

Here is the scope of the entire array iteration, it's fairly simple:

```
array= @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links
array.each_with_index do |i, index|
  if index == array.length-1
    sleep 1
    @browser.button(:text => 'Complete').when_present.click
  else
    sleep 1
    @browser.button(:text => 'Complete').when_present.click
    @browser.a(:text => 'Next').when_present.click
  end
end
```

I am trying to add an `elsif` that checks for the text of a link, so that if it's on that particular page/link it does something specific while on that page.

For example, in pseudo-code:

> If array element text = "Instructions", then dont click the complete button, just click next.

I suppose I would be open to solving this in any way that lets me identify the link it is currently on, so that I can perform a set action, but I figured grabbing the text of the current link would be easiest, hence the question.

How can I access the text or specific attributes of an element in this array?

Comment: Between the time you create the `array` and then call `array[index]`, are you performing any actions that would refresh part of the page?

Comment: Probably. Basically the iteration moves thru each link. So it clicks on a "complete" button that hides some stuff on the page, then clicks on a "next" button that moves it to the next link in the array. Then then next iteration begins and it does it again. I can update with the whole section of array code if that will help. When ive tried the array[index](i was trying to find out if and how i could access the text) it was in debug mode on the click the complete button step, so when an element should be loaded from the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Only having a description of the problem makes us try to imagine what you're doing, but having code and data makes it very obvious. We can give you broad answers but Stack Overflow is about detailed answers. Please provide more information, including the minimal code/data necessary to demonstrate the problem. It doesn't have to use Watir, simply recreate the minimum structure in your code. It helps us help you.

Comment: It's not clear where exactly it fails, which line? It might be unable to locate :text => 'Next' in second part of conditional, as well as :text => 'Complete' in the first one. On the other hand, logically you are missing additional else if, where it should simply continue. Please update your question, and possible give us an URL or jsfiddle it.

Comment: It doesnt fail on any of those lines. It fails with the code above because of how the particular page works, which is why i need a different condition. the question, is how to identify that im on that particular page. I assumed it would be easy to just grab the text from the element in the array it was on, but that hasnt proven to be the case. The HTML for this section of the page would be fairly large But i can add it if people think it will help find a solution. Based on the question, I wasnt sure if html would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the DOMs of your elements are changing after some interaction (like clicking 'Complete' button).

My suggestion is to find all the elements once again after each interaction.

Try something like that:

```
array = @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links
index = 0
array.length.times do
  sleep 1
  if index == array.length-1
    @browser.button(:text => 'Complete').when_present.click
    array = @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links #We are finding new array after possible change
  elsif  array[index].text == 'Instructions'
    @browser.a(:text => 'Next').when_present.click
  else
    @browser.button(:text => 'Complete').when_present.click
    @browser.a(:text => 'Next').when_present.click
  end
  array = @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links #And once again
  index = index+1
end
```

Attention: I can not guarantee that the code above will work because I've got no page to test it on to be sure. If it is not working - try to modify it using the idea

Comment: So, something like array[index].text SHOULD pull back the text of the element? That is kind of the original question, HOW do i get the text. If this should be working, then I can adjust to how to resolve it. When i tried the above i was in debug mode, so it was sitting on the same page and same screen for minutes at a time, so refreshing the DOM shouldnt have been an issue, it had plenty of time to reset.

Comment: Yes. I even rechecked it. array[1].text gives the text of element.

Comment: This specific code wasnt going to work, but the concept was the right answer. I had to wait on page refresh and rebuild the array after each NON instructions page. So far its working.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a list of links and just pulling out information on them is fairly simple and should work reliably as long as the DOM is not changing.  Once you start clicking things, or taking actions that cause some or all of the page to update, all bets are off as your collection may contain references to elements in the UI that have been deleted or replaced.

You also seem a bit confused over how the .each iterator works.  The basic form of that method returns you each object in the collection in turn.  The with_index version returns each object plus its index within the array.  In most cases, unless you care what the index is, you would not use the with_index form.

For example, to walk your collection and output the text of each link, you could simply do

```
links_list = @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links
links_list.each do |link|
  puts "the link text is: #{link.text}"
end
```

If you wanted to indicate the index of each link, then you could do

```
links_list = @browser.ul(:class => 'parent').links
links_list.each_with_index do |link, index|
  puts "the text for link number #{index} is: #{link.text}"
end
```

If you want to work your way through a list of links like that and *do things* with them that might cause page updates, then you are better off to use a tactic like that presented in the other answer where you create a loop based off the size of the list, but re-fetch the list inside the loop so that it will always be 'fresh' and not potentially contain references to objects that are no longer in the DOM.